# 「んだって」と「って」どう違いますか。

Tags: verbs, word-usage, spoken-language

例えば「彼が結婚してるんだって」と「彼が結婚してるって」どう違いますか。

Comment: related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56630/4216 (no answers there though)

Answer (score 1):

意味的には同じです。ただ、「んだ」は助詞「の」と断定の助動詞「だ」からできた略語で、普通の「って」と比べれば断定を含む「んだって」の方がより強い表現に聞こえます。

その違いから生じるニュアンスとしては、「って」の場合では、直接聞いた情報のように聞こえることが多いのに対して、「んだって」の場合では、既に永劫回帰さんが述べたように、少し主観的な感じがすることがあります。

他にはないからあまり考えないで使っても誤解が生じることはないでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

どっちも伝聞を言い表す表現ですが、「んだって」のほうがもっと主観的だとは言えるでしょう。